# for (const i) rather than for (var i)

Tags: actionscript-3, for-loop, compiler-errors, constants, var

Although the intelligent code completion doesn't seem to get it (in Flash Builder at least), the compiler seems that it does allow it and it's far more bug-protective to define a ***for*** iterator variable as a constant.

```
        for (const i:int = 0; i < 100; ++i) {
            i = 5; // this breaks the loop's logic, but is caught by the compiler
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot change the value of a `const`, `const` refers to the programming concept of [Constants](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constant_(programming)), properties that can never change. You cannot increment a `const`, you can only assign to a `const` once. After that point, it is fixed until it is disposed. A `const` is a poor choice as a counter in a for loop because you can not change it's value. You can learn more about actionscripts implementation of `const` [here](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ActionScript/3.0_ProgrammingAS3/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118a9b90204-7f9b.html#WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118a9b90204-7f6d).

According to this [document](http://helpx.adobe.com/flash-builder/actionscript-compiler-backward-compatibility.html) there was a bug in the legacy complier that allowed increment operators to work on `const`, this bug should have been addressed in Actionscript Complier 2.0, if this code works, most likely explaination is that you are using the legacy complier.

If you are using ASC 2.0 or greater all I can tell you is that this behaviour contradicts the [Actionscript 3 language rules](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ActionScript/3.0_ProgrammingAS3/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118a9b90204-7f9b.html#WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118a9b90204-7f6d) and you shouldn't depend on it. It's most likely a bug that could be fixed at the whim of Adobe.

Comment: If in my code you remove i=5 and put a trace(i), you will see it incremented up to 100 so yes, it does get incremented by the for-loop!!

Comment: Seems you might be using the legacy complier, see my updated answer.

Comment: I thought using Flash Builder 4.6 would have included the latest Compiler. Maybe I should find a way to update it and check again...